# loop through several vectors

Tags: c++

I had trouble searching for potential duplicates because I'm not sure what the correct terminology is.

If I have many vectors which are already created, how can I loop through them? To make things simple, suppose I have three vectors of strings named `"vec_one"`, `"vec_two"`, `"vec_three"`.

I want to do something like:

```
for i in ("vec_one", "vec_two", "vec_three") {
    for (vector<string>::const_iterator iter = i.begin(); iter != i.end(); ++iter) {
        //do something with the elements ***and I need to access "i"***, that is, the vector name.
    }
}
```

This would be the same as writing three different for loops, but would be more readable and in fact I have more than three in my non-simple application.

Note that because I need to access the vector name (see the comment), I can't just merge them all together and then run one loop.

Comment: Make an array of pointers (or references) to `vec_one`, `vec_two` etc... Outer loop goes through array of these pointers, access in inner loop by outer loop's index.

Comment: @AzzA you can't make an array of references

Comment: @SethCarnegie You are right, my bad.

Comment: If it weren't for your need to have the name of each vector, you could use [`join`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/join.html) from [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) to build a list of iterator ranges *without* physically merging them all together. [I wrote a short example.](https://gist.github.com/1686647)

Comment: @RobKennedy thanks, that is definitely good to know for the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the the vectors in a `vector<std::pair<std::string, std::vector<...>*>`:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::vector<std::string>*> > vectors;
vectors.emplace_back(std::string("vec_one"), &vec_one); //or push_back(std::make_pair(...)) in C++03
vectors.emplace_back(std::string("vec_two"), &vec_two); 
vectors.emplace_back(std::string("vec_three"), &vec_three); 
for(auto iter = vectors.begin(); iter != vectors.end(); ++iter)//used c++11 auto here for brevity, but that isn't necessary if C++11 is not availible
    for(auto vecIter = iter->second->begin(); vecIter != iter->second->end(); ++vecIter)
    //get name with iter->first, body here
```

That way you can get the name easily from the outer iterator.

If you use C++11 you can use `std::array` instead:

```
std::array<std::pair<std::string, std::vector<std::string>*>, 3> vectors =
{
    std::make_pair(std::string("vec_one"), &vec_one),
    std::make_pair(std::string("vec_two"), &vec_two),
    std::make_pair(std::string("vec_three"), &vec_three)
};
```

In C++03 you could use buildin arrays instead, but unless the extra overhead for the `vector` is a problem for you (unlikely) I don't see a compelling reason to do so. `boost::array` is also a noteworthy alternative if you can't use C++11

If you do need the absolute optimal performance it might be worthwile to directly use `const char*` instead of `std::string` for the names.

Comment: Thank you, Grizzly. I especially appreciate the different options that you allow. Unfortunately, I must use C++03.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer: An explanation for the downvote would be nice, since I don't see what is wrong with with this answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with an array:

```
const vector<string>* varr[] = { &vec_one, &vec_two, &vec_three, &etc };

for (auto vec = begin(varr); vec < end(varr); ++vec)
    for (vector<string>::const_iterator iter = begin(**vec); iter != end(**vec); ++iter)
        //do something with the elements
```

Comment: Thank you, Seth. This seems like the most natural way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way would be to have your vectors in an array (or a vector-of-vectors if there is a variable number of them).

I guess you'd also want an array of "vector names" to satisfy your second condition.